# Java Iterator implementation - next() and hasNext() enforcing order

Tags: java, concurrency, iterator

I have an implementation of `java.util.Iterator` which requires that the call to `next()` should always be proceeded by a call to `hasNext()`. (This is because results are returned asynchronosly in a multi threaded environment and it is never clear how many more results there might be).

Would it be 'correct' to properly document this in the JavaDoc and then throw a `RuntimeException` if this was violated.  Or is this stretching the Iterator interface a little too far?

All thoughts appreciated?

Comment: After reflection and all the great answers I have come to the conclusion that the problem is the Iterator interface.

There should be just one method next() which returns null (or a poison pill) when it has reached the end.

Do you agree?

Comment: I disagree. Firstly, null could be a valid element of an Iterable. Secondly, given generic type erasure, how would you ensure that your poison pill was of type T but somehow not a valid return value otherwise? (I dismiss out of hand any argument where next() does not return an instance of type T).

Comment: @ILMTitan I take your points but don't think that a special object of type Poison Pill would do any harm even if it is not of type T.  The alternative (having two methods) is far worse.

Comment: The harm the special object of type Poison Pill would cause would be forcing the return type of next() to change from T to Object. That in turn would cause every call to next to have to call an instanceOf followed by a cast. Over any moderately sized project, that is a huge amount of boilerplate code (exactly the same boilerplate that generics were supposed to get rid of in the first place. I don't understand your problem with the two method solution, which has an easy to understand method for bounds checking, and throws an exception when you do something stupid.

Comment: So by the Poison Pill type, are you talking about the Null Object Pattern?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but why not call `hasNext()` internally in your implementation?

Comment: I could do that but I'd rather not - just want to enforce the pattern of usage which mean that the user should always call hasNext() first.

Comment: @Dan I always try to make it hard for the client to use an API the wrong way, and I think demanding something to be called before something else is called makes an API very easy to be used in the wrong way.

Comment: Disagree - I think calling next() without first calling hasNext() is wrong.  I would be enforcing the generally accepted correct usage.

Comment: I think you are not right here. Generally it is accepted, that in most cases routines should do the work they are assigned to without depending on a call-order. For instance, if you have some object over data and you want calculate a report, don't say the user of the API should call first calculateReport() and then multiple times getReportColumn(). Instead calculateReport should return a Report-object, that allows to accces the report-columns. Same here: next() should work without relying on a special call-order, especially since it is specified that you can call next() alone.

Comment: @Dan: Iterators are defined in the library with a particular set of semantics. Any usage that abides to those semantics is correct. When defining your own iterator if your semantics differ from the standard iterators you are probably confusing users and making your code `harder`. While I can only agree in that the correct usage is checking `hasNext()` before `next()`, the correct response from the iterator is throwing `NoSuchElementException` only if there are no more elements. When forcing correctness you should not only require it from your users but also from your own implementation.

Comment: The Iterator interface does not mandate a particular call order, so if your implementation requires on you are violating the contract of the interface. Documenting in your implementation is not useful when instances may be passed to something that has no knowledge of your implementation (and may even predate it).

Answer (score 15):

Requiring that `hasNext()` be called before `next()` violates the `iterator` contract. You really should rewrite it so that `next()` simply throws a `NoSuchElementException` if there is no element to return.

Comment: Why does it violate the Iterator contract?

Comment: @Dan: Because `next()` has only two valid results: returning the next value or throwing a `NoSuchElementException` when there is no next element. Since you'd throw an exception, even if there were a next element, you're violating the contract.

Comment: Agreed, throwing the NoSuchElementException is the correct behavior here. The hasNext() method is a guard method to avoid having to deal with the exception (as in if hasNext() returns true, next() should never throw the exception).

Comment: For this answer to be complete I think it really should specify exactly what part of the specification that you think is violated.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I think you misunderstood the question to be about `RuntimeException` versus `NoSuchElementException`, when it really seems to be about throw or not-to-throw.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Ah, now I understand the reasoning in your comment! I think it all comes down to what "*no next element*" really means in the documentation. I posted an answer where I try to argue against this one.

Answer (score 8):

I imagine you're doing something like this:

```
class IteratorImpl<T> implements Iterator<T> {
  private Source<T> source = ...
  private T next = null;

  public boolean hasNext() {
    if(next == null) {
      next = source.poll();
    }
    return next != null;
  }
```

That sounds OK to me. I can't imagine a situation where you'd want to use `next` without `hasNext` - it would be a recipe for exceptions.

---

EDIT:

The [doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext()) for `hasNext()` says:

> Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)

To me, the implementation does not violate the contract. However, I would (as [Fabian Steeg implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176212/java-iterator-implementation/2176237#2176237)) still implement `next()` as:

```
  public T next() {
    if(!hasNext()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    T ret = next;
    next = null;
    return ret;
  }
```

I mean, what does that check really cost you?

You must check and throw a `NoSuchElementException` as per the [API contract](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()). Either testing on `!hasNext()` or `next == null` will meet this criteria, I believe, but I would favour the former.

If someone is catching `NoSuchElementException` instead of calling `hasNext()`, you probably have bigger problems.

Comment: Exactly what I want to do - but is Ucleman right that it voilates the Iterator contract?

Comment: @Dan - by my interpretation of the documentation, I don't believe this violates the contract.

Comment: Pretty much every iterator I've ever written (which is many) has begun its next() implementation with those same three lines you illustrate here.

Comment: This is the right answer, next() should always call hasNext() first in all but the most rare instances.  Otherwise you are either a) duplicating code, or b) doing a different 'hasNext' check internally than what you are providing to the caller... which is dangerous from a consistency perspective.

Answer (score 4):

If your `hasNext()` and `next()` calls aren't in a synchronized block/method, it is not guaranteed that you will have elements even if you call `hasNext()` before `next()`.

The contract of the `Iterator` interface is that `NoSuchElementException` should be thrown if there are no more elements. So proceed with the `next()` method until such an exception arises.

That said, take a look at the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package - it has concurrent collections whose iterators may help you - i.e. you can use these collections and iterators instead of implementing your own.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear - the Iterator will be accessed in a single threaded environment - internally results will be produced to it in a multi threaded environment.

Comment: the same iterator cannot be used in two different environments. If it is accessed in any way from multiple-threads, then it's he einvoronment is multi-threaded

Answer (score 2):

I would rather throw an exception from `next()`, when there are no  more elements. In a multi-threaded environment `hasNext()` is pretty useless anyway.

Comment: It's quite rare for an iterator to be designed to be shared between threads.

Comment: You don't need to share the *iterator*. Sharing the underlying *collection* is enough to make the iterator "essentially shared".

Comment: But yes, taking it into account is rare, as you wrote. But there definitely are practical uses for a thread-safe iterator; for instance, purging a queue using parallel consumers. It's quite useful when there are multiple processors/cores in use.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is implement the `Iterator` interface yourself (if you need to interface with other API) and ask your clients to implement your own stricter interface.

I created such a class in my functional programming library in order to easily implement an `Iterator` around a `ResultSet` in a project at work.

My class [EasierIterator](http://bitbucket.org/genezys/functional/src/tip/src/fr/cantor/functional/EasierIterator.java) implements the Iterator interface while requiring that the client implements a simpler interface based on `moveNext()`/`getCurrent()`. It actually does the caching of the current item for you.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Coming from .NET where the enumerator interface is just `Current` and `MoveNext`, the Java iterator interface was driving me crazy trying to figure out how to sanely deal with iterators where the only thing you can do is "get next or null".  I am not sure how Java ended up with this `hasNext` and `next` interface, it seems to only make sense for trivial types like in-memory arrays where peeking at the next item is a cheap and repeatable operation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to the below, whereby you delegate the underlying data fetch to a private method, and implement `hasNext()` and `next()` to react differently to the absence of data.  This has the advantage that you can repeatedly call `next()` without calling `hasNext()` first, and hence **do not violate the contract of Iterator**.

```
public class IteratorImpl<T> implements Iterator<T> {
  private final Source<T> source;
  private T next;

  public synchronized boolean hasNext() {
    tryGetNext();
    return next != null;
  }

  public synchronized T next() {
    tryGetNext();

    if (next == null) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } 

    return next;
  }

  private void tryGetNext() {
    if (next != null) {
      next = source.poll();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's actually what I did implement in the end!
However I was just exploring the possibility of enforcing the order of method calls.

Comment: The use of volatile might not synch with the question, since it was stated as only be accessed by a single thread, is there another reason it's used here?

Also, in tryGetNext(), since the operation is dependent on the value of next, shouldn't a AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater be used?

Comment: Agreed - I'm not sure why I wrote it like this as it's clearly not thread-safe even with volatile; there's potential for 2 threads to both call next and both end up calling source.poll().  I'll amend to make it fully thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** In this answer I tried to argue that it is allowed what the question asks about. But I overlooked one sentence in the `Iterator.hasNext` documentation which invalidates my whole reasoning:

> In other words, returns true if `next()` would return an element rather than throwing an exception.

This seems to imply that calling `next` repeatedly until `hasNext` returns true and calling next until you get a `NoSuchElementException` should return the same sequence of elements.

Thus it seems that what the question asks about is *not* allowed.

### Original answer

This is an attempt on a specification lawyer type of answer. For clarity I'll restate the question in a compact form:

> Is it allowed by the `Iterable` specification to throw a `NoSuchElementException` when  `Iterator.next` is called without a preceding call to `Iterator.hasNext`, even if an element would have been return had `Iterator.hasNext` been called first?

### Discussion

The documentation for [`Iterator.hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--) states:

> Returns true if the iteration has more elements.

And for [`Iterator.next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--):

> Throws: `NoSuchElementException` - if the iteration has no more elements

Apparently it's allowed to throw `NoSuchElementException` when "the iteration has no more elements", but not before that. That should coincide with when `hasNext` returns false.

This leads to the question: Exactly what does the documentation mean with "the iteration" and "elements"? The `Iterator` documentation does not give an answer to that, which gives some wiggling space for implementers.

In my view there are two possible interpretations:

1. From the perspective of the iterator interface itself the only existing concept of "iteration" is "as long as `hasNext` returns true". That implies that if the client calls `next` before `hasNext` they doesn't know if there are more elements, it's undefined.

   It is hence allowed by the specification for the iterator implementer to decide that the iteration has finished. So the answer to the question is yes.
2. But the documentation on [`Iterable.iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator--) also mention "elements":

   > Returns an iterator over elements of type `T`.

   So what does "elements" mean here? Does it mean "all elements in the collection implementing `Iterable`? No, it doesn't say so, and not all iterables even *have* a fixed set of elements.

   What "elements" mean for some particular iterable is left for the implementer to decide. A valid definition of "elements" for an iterator could be "*all of the elements in the collection, OR, all elements before the client decides to call `next` before `hasNext`*".

   So this case also leads to the conclusion that the answer to the question is yes. (But please see the note on the end!)

### Conclution

The documentation is not really clear, but it seem like the answer to the question is: Yes, this is allowed.

### Note

In case that an iterator does what the question asks about that behaviour should be documented of course. But other iterables should also document over which elements their iterators are.

For example, the [`ArrayList.iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator--) documentation clearly states *which* elements the iterator is over:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.

---

<sup>*Final note: Yes, I am crazy to spend so much time on this.*</sup>

Comment: I think this is overcomplicating the situation. `hasNext` is clearly meant as a non-mutating method that merely queries the status "do we have another element" and both "`hasNext()` returns false" and "`next()` throws a `NoSuchElementException`" are specified using the same phrasing. If you need a class that behaves the way the question describes that's fine, but I think making it implement `Iterator` is a mistake.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: It might be an mistake. I agree that it is pretty weird. In this answer I try to see it from a specification layer point of view here.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: On the other hand, `next` is clearly meant to be called before `hasNext`, so the client is kind of performing undefined operations and should expect unexpected behaviour. The question is: How much extra trouble should I make for myself when implementing my iterator in order to support this weird behaviour by clients, instead of creating a simpler but a little bit weird iterator?

Comment: I agree that all of this is rules lawyering, but I'll continue: yes. `hasNext` is *meant* to be called before `next`, I agree with that (just because catching avoidable exceptions is a code smell). However, it is **not** undefined behaviour to only use `next` on an Iterator: if will return all values and then throw a `NoSuchElementException` on the next call. There are even some blocking "infinite" `Iterator` implementations that always return `true` from `hasNext` and just block on `next` when the next element is not available yet. Also ugly, but technically valid.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Hm. I now noticed another sentence in the `hasNext` documentation which I overlooked before: "_In other words, returns true if **`next()` would return an element rather than throwing an exception.**_" This actually seem to be direct support for your position in the documentation. It seems to imply that calling `next` until `hasNext` returns true and calling `next` until you get a `NoSuchElementException` should return the same sequence of elements.